# Замена TextBlock на TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите способ редактирования в RunTime.

У меня есть `TextBlock` на форме WPF. По нажатии кнопки "Редактирование", хотелось бы что-бы это поле (`TextBlock`), можно было бы редактировать. Как лучше поступить?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вариантов множество:

- Изначально размещать `TextBox`, а не `TextBlock`, но блокировать редактирование (устанавливать `ReadOnly`/`Enabled` в `false`)
- Вместе с `TextBlock` размещать сразу `TextBox` и [управлять их видимостью](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2902eee1-3fd8-4481-b636-baef0f862efb/change-textblock-into-textbox-after-click-on-button). [Другой пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024127/1985167):

  ```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text="Str: " Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
      <Grid Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Center">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Strength}" 
              Visibility="{Binding IsEditing, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToInvisibilityConverter}}"
              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Strength}" 
              Visibility="{Binding IsEditing, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
      </Grid>
  </StackPanel>
  ```
- Воспользоваться кастомным TextBlock, который разрешает редактирование: [раз](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/72544/Editable-Text-Block-in-WPF), [два](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31592/Editable-TextBlock-in-WPF-for-In-place-Editing)

Answer (score 0):

Для варианта 1.
 Изначально размещать `TextBox`, а не `TextBlock`, но блокировать редактирование (устанавливать `ReadOnly`/`Enabled` в `false`)

Можно сделать через стили.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Tag, ElementName=ucClientViewInfo}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Style.Setters>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="TextBox.IsEnabled" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```